# how to compare the answer of authority.getAuthority() with a specific role 'ROLE_ADMIN' in thymeleaf?

Tags: thymeleaf

I have tried the code below, but getting `false` even for `ROLE_ADMIN`

```
<th:block th:each="authority : ${#authentication.getAuthorities()}">
     <span  th:with="role=${authority.getAuthority()}">
         <span th:text="${role}"></span>
         <p th:with="res=${#strings.toString(role) == 'ROLE_ADMIN'}">
            <div th:if="${res}">successtrial</div>
            <div th:unless="${res}">failed trial</div>
            <span th:text=${res}></span>
     </span>
        </p>      
</th:block>
```

Getting `${role}` - printed correct, but finally getting failed trial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `hasRole` method like this:

```
<div sec:authorize="hasRole('ADMIN')">
  <div>success trial</div>
</div>
<div sec:authorize="!hasRole('ADMIN')">
  <div>failed trial</div>
</div>
```

Be sure to have the `org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5` dependency in your application.

Comment: Can you add more details? "not working for me" is not very clear to understand what the problem is.

Comment: Above answer is correct, but My issue is because of  blank spaces added up with 'ROLE_ADMIN ' value in table, updated the value as well changed the datatype as varchar - solved the issue